# How to implement a generic arrow function as interface property in Typescript with React JSX

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, type-inference

I am trying to create an

```
interface PromptInput {
  key: string,
  title: string,
  customInput?: <T>(value: T, onChange: (newValue: T) => void) => React.ReactNode;
}
```

I want the types of `value` and `newValue` to be the same, but they can be anything.

I have a component `InputPromptDialog` which has a prop `inputs: PromptInput[]`

But when I try to pass arguments I get an error:

```
<InputPromptDialog
  inputs={[
    { key: 'fullName', title: 'Full Name' },
    { key: 'email', title: 'Email' },
    { key: 'role', title: 'Role', customInput: (value, onChange) => <RoleSelector onChange={(selectedRoleId: string) => onChange(selectedRoleId)} /> },
  ]}
/>
```

The error is with the `selectedRole` value I am passing to `onChange`, and says

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'.ts(2345)
```

Why is the value of T not inferred? How can I enforce `value` and `newValue` to be the same type, but still be any type?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I seem to have figured out a fix:

By creating a

```
type PromptInputCustomInput<T> = (value: T, onChange: (newValue: T) => void) => React.ReactNode;
```

and changing the interface to:

```
interface PromptInput {
  key: string,
  title: string,
  customInput?: PromptInputCustomInput<any>;
}
```

and changing where I pass the arguments to:

```
<InputPromptDialog
  inputs={[
    { key: 'fullName', title: 'Full Name' },
    { key: 'email', title: 'Email' },
    { key: 'role', title: 'Role', customInput: ((value, onChange) => <RoleSelector onChange={(selectedRoleId: string) => onChange(selectedRoleId)} />) as PromptInputCustomInput<string> },
  ]}
/>
```

This creates the desired result I am looking for. But I would still be interested to know if there is a way of doing this without having to always cast the values I am passing `as PromptInputCustomInput<DESIRED_TYPE>`